# Unable to run lighthouse cli using process builder from eclipse Error"windows cannot find lighthouse"

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, processbuilder, lighthouse

Has anyone used the Node CLI version of the Google Chrome Lighthouse to collect performance metrics. i'm able to do it from commandline without any issues. when i tried to run the same command through process builder from eclipse it is not able to recognize the command lighthouse.Please find the below steps i followed.

1) Downloaded nodejs msi installer for windows

2) Nodejs and npm path is set automatically. i did double check that.

I'm able to get node and npm version using below commands:

```
node -v
v8.12.0

npm -v
6.4.1
```

I used below command as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) to install lighthouse with -g flag to install as a global module.

```
npm install -g lighthouse
```

Sample java code used to run lighthouse from eclipse:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Invoke_Lighthouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Process p;
        {
               try {


                   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait lighthouse  http://demo.testfire  --output json --output-path ./light.json  --disable-device-emulation --throttling-method=provided");

            } catch (IOException  e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

i keep getting the error "windows cannot find lighthouse". the same command is working through commandline. I'm trying to automate things here. i want this to work in java. am i missing anything here any advise on this would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c lighthouse http://demo.testfire")